# PostgreSQL foreign key with inheritance

Tags: sql, postgresql, inheritance

I have a PostgreSQL database, 3 tables and my schema as follows.
[image]

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name_a VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE table_b (
    name_b VARCHAR(255) 
) INHERITS (table_a);

CREATE TABLE table_c (
    name_c VARCHAR(255)
) INHERITS (table_a);

insert into table_b (name_a, name_b) values('table A','table B1');
insert into table_b (name_a, name_b) values('table A','table B2');
insert into table_c (name_a, name_c) values('table A','table C1');
insert into table_c (name_a, name_c) values('table A','table C2');

select * from table_a;
select * from table_b;
select * from table_c;
```

[image]

Now i want to add an association between `Table B`and `Table C` like this:

[image]

I do not know if this is possible when we inherit the same table ?

I do not see how I can create this association ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a unique identifier or primary key on `table_b`. Quoting docs:

> All check constraints and not-null constraints on a parent table are automatically inherited by its children, unless explicitly specified otherwise with NO INHERIT clauses. **Other types of constraints (unique, primary key, and foreign key constraints) are not inherited**.

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name_a VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE table_b (
    name_b VARCHAR(255),
    primary key (id)     --> here you set the PK
) INHERITS (table_a);

CREATE TABLE table_c (
    name_c VARCHAR(255),
    id_b int references table_b(id) --> the fk to b through pk
) INHERITS (table_a);
```

**Alternative way**

In your second diagram, do you have a kind of identifier for `table_b`. It is right because you can reference  table by a unique field. In this case, the DDL will be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name_a VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE table_b (
    name_b VARCHAR(255),
    id_b SERIAL UNIQUE     --> Here the unique id for b
    --, primary key (id)   -- optionally
) INHERITS (table_a);

CREATE TABLE table_c (
    name_c VARCHAR(255),
    id_b int references table_b(id_b)  --> the fk to b through unique
) INHERITS (table_a);
```

*I prefer the first approach, but I have posted also this one just for academical purposes.*

Comment: my column `id_b` of my Table C is `null`

Comment: @Mercer, thanks about your comments. I improved my answer. Also, you can found an example with FK here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kG1Vxo8jMWsNsVRvREfapr/0